# Adding byte* data to double vector

Tags: c++, vector, double, byte

How to convert a byte buffer to a double vector. The calling function passes a byte* variable.
At the receiving end I have to add the byte buffer into a double vector. How can I do this.Please help.

Comment: That really depends on what the `byte` buffer actually encodes. If the bytes are the correct format for doubles independent of the machine you just cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a pointer to byte(s) to a `std:vector<double>`. You have to find out, what you have to to be reading the specification. Probably you need to request the spec.

A `byte*` is sometimes used as a universal type pointing to something. If it points to more than one byte you need at least two things:

- the type of the actual data where the `byte*` points to the count of
- the data items.

Ask your customer (probable yourself?).

Comment: the byte* type is pixel data of an image's one frame.Actually I meant adding this to the vector not converting.sorry for the mistake. I have also the size of the byte* data as another argument.

Comment: @CodeRider So you want to add pixel elements to a double vector? Sounds strange for me, but that might work for you. Does one of my two guesses match your intention? Try to explain, what you want to do.